# Newey-West p-values in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there a command to calculate the p-values for the Newey-West correction?

The matlab [helpfiles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/hac.html) state that the hac command is used to estimate Newey-West but I can't find out which option to use to display the p-values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple to calculate yourself and isn't Newey-West specific once you have the covariance matrix for your estimator.

Let `BCOV` be the covariance matrix for your estimates `b`. First, calculate the standard error of your estimator:

```
bse = diag(BCOV).^.5;
```

Let `b` be a vector of your estimated coefficients. Now calculate t-stats:

```
t = b ./ bse;
```

Let `df_r` be the degrees of freedom of your residuals, i.e., `n-k` where `n` is number of observations and `k` is number of coefficients you're estimating. Now calculate pvals:

```
pvals = NaN(size(b));
pvals(t >= 0) = 2 * (1 - tcdf(t(t>=0), df_r));
pvals(t < 0)  = 2 * tcdf(t(t<0), df_r);
```

And if you want, 95% confidence interval:

```
conf95 = [b + bse * tinv(.025, df_r), b + bse * tinv(.975, df_r)];
```